# UML relationship calculation

Tags: uml, relationship

[image: simple noatated diagram]

(a) If there are 6 authors, what's the minimum and the maximum number of books? What's the minimum and the maximum number of readers?
(b) If there are 6 readers, what's the minimum and the maximum number of books? What's the minimum and the maximum number of authors?

Comment: stack overflow Isn't a homework writing service. is there a specific problem you are struggling with?

Comment: yes, I'm not able to understand how the relationships work in a generic formula if we replace it with another formula

Comment: Just read the numbers. An author can have 1 to 3 books (wut?) and a book can have one to two authors (poor third, forth etc. author). In practice this is just rubbish, but that's what it says. Print it 10.000 times in a book and bag it on the (diagram) author's head.

Comment: I was able to solve part of the question (a) what about the second part (b). Didn't get you honestly!!

Comment: Well, this is simple combinatorics (school knowledge; IIRC 10th grade). 6 readers have min. 6 books and max. 6*5 = 30 books.  Go have some private coaching in maths.

Comment: Probably I did not account, that a book can have at max. 4 readers. So it's not 30 but less.

Comment: (a) Books: minimum 3, maximum 18; Readers: minimum 0, maximum 72
(b) Books: minimum 2, maximum unlimited; Authors: minimum 1, maximum unlimited. sorry to tell you that you are mistaken Thomas Kilian

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the exact numbers, just create an instance diagram according to the class diagram. I'll show you the a) part of the questions. Minimum: You've got six authors, so draw six objects typed by an Author. Every author must have at least one book. So draw one object typed by a Book. Well, every book can have up to two authors. Well, draw two links between the book and two authors. You still have 4 authors without a book. Repeat the steps above. You will end up with 3 books and 6 links. As for the Readers: there is no need do have one connected with a book. So the minimum is zero. If you did it well you should have something like this:

[image: 6 authors, minimum books and readers]

The similar way you do with the maximum. You will ended up with this:

[image]

So now you are able to do the b) part of your question.